# Rails ActiveRecord includes syntax for multiple parent/ child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The way my models are set up:

- an Order object has many RentalItems & TypeLogistics
- RentalItem & TypeLogistic objects each has many ChargedAmounts & Refunds
- further, the Order object itself has many ChargedAmounts & Refunds

The following queries appear to be working correctly, for when I want to eager load the stated associations for the 19th Order object in db:

```
# Load order, and its charged_amounts & refunds
@order = Order.includes(:charged_amounts, :refunds).find(19)
=>
Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
ChargedAmount Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "charged_amounts".* FROM "charged_amounts"  WHERE "charged_amounts"."order_id" IN (19)
Refund Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "refunds".* FROM "refunds"  WHERE "refunds"."order_id" IN (19)

# Load order, its type_logistics, and the charged_amounts & refunds that belong to each type_logistic
@order = Order.includes(type_logistics:[:charged_amounts, :refunds]).find(19)
=>
Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
TypeLogistic Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "type_logistics".* FROM "type_logistics"  WHERE "type_logistics"."order_id" IN (19)
ChargedAmount Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "charged_amounts".* FROM "charged_amounts"  WHERE "charged_amounts"."type_logistic_id" IN (26)
Refund Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refunds".* FROM "refunds"  WHERE "refunds"."type_logistic_id" IN (26)

# Load order, its rental_items, and the charged_amounts & refunds that belong to each rental_item
@order = Order.includes(rental_items: [:charged_amounts, :refunds]).find(19)
=>
Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
RentalItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rental_items".* FROM "rental_items"  WHERE "rental_items"."order_id" IN (19)
ChargedAmount Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "charged_amounts".* FROM "charged_amounts"  WHERE "charged_amounts"."rental_item_id" IN (27, 28)
Refund Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refunds".* FROM "refunds"  WHERE "refunds"."rental_item_id" IN (27, 28)
```

But the challenge is that I want to eager load ALL of it: the order's charged_amounts and refunds, and all of its rental_items and type_logistics and the charged_amounts and refunds for each rental_item and type_logistic.

But when I string the query together, it looks like the second set of associations (type_logistics and its charged_amounts and refunds) aren't loading at all based on the queries.

```
@order = Order.includes(:charged_amounts, :refunds, rental_items: [:charged_amounts, :refunds], type_logistics:[:charged_amounts, :refunds]).find(19)
=>
Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
ChargedAmount Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "charged_amounts".* FROM "charged_amounts"  WHERE "charged_amounts"."order_id" IN (19)
Refund Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refunds".* FROM "refunds"  WHERE "refunds"."order_id" IN (19)
RentalItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rental_items".* FROM "rental_items"  WHERE "rental_items"."order_id" IN (19)
ChargedAmount Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "charged_amounts".* FROM "charged_amounts"  WHERE "charged_amounts"."rental_item_id" IN (27, 28)
Refund Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refunds".* FROM "refunds"  WHERE "refunds"."rental_item_id" IN (27, 28)
```

But the charged_amounts and refunds on the order don't have any other associations, so they're not the "key" for anything. Any assistance here?

Answer (score 1):

An approach I have followed in previous projects is:

```
Order.eager_load(:charged_amounts, :refunds)
      .eager_load(rental_items: [:charged_amounts, :refunds])
      .eager_load(type_logistics: [:charged_amounts, :refunds] )
      .find(19)
```

I don't know if this may be the solution. Also note that I'm using the `AR.eager_load` method. Feel free to swap that for `AR.includes`

Comment: ah so that worked! but i'm going to keep this question open in case someone can help me understand why the other syntax doesn't, thanks!